# pass result of express.js routed function to another routed function

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm still finding my feet with node.js / express.js. I would like to pass the result of one rest web service to another... or create a new routed service from two web service functions...

function A connects to mysql and builds a json object

e.g.

url:port/getMySQLRecord/:recordid

function B add a new document (JSON object) to a mongoDB collection

it accepts an AJAX POST

e.g.

url:port/insertMongoDoc

function A and B both currently work as REST web services... (how can I best pipe the result of A to B?)

it seems inefficient for the HTTP client to call A and pass the results to B.

I mean using 2 x bandwidth when the server already has the object data doesn't seem the best option.

if this were nix I'd be using | ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//pseudocode loadRecord middleware just queries mysql for req.params.recordid
// and stores the result as req.body, then calls next()

//storeReqDotBodyInMongo just takes req.body and does a mongo insert, then calls next()

//sendResponse is just res.send(req.body)


app.get('/getMySQLRecord/:recordid', loadRecord, sendResponse);
app.post('/insertMongoDoc', express.bodyParser(), storeReqDotBodyInMongo, sendResponse);
app.get('/getMySQLAndInsertMongo/:record', loadRecord, storeReqDotBodyInMongo, sendResponse);
```

Note the similarity of connect middleware to unix pipes. Just instead of stdio they use req/res/next.

Comment: OK great I got it!! Thanks to your explanation. 

the first two routes (already) in my server.js (map to separate .js files lets say mysqlfunctions.js and mongofunctions.js but this doesn't matter)

server.js does the routing with the final route... makes me think of one of those lawn mowers that cutGrass and creates fertiliseGrass - the mulcher ;)

`app.get('/MULCH/:recordid', cutGrass, fertiliseGrass , sendResponse)`

thanks Peter.